# luabind and static fields

Tags: c++, static, lua, luabind

I'm trying to export static fields from class:

```
class Foo
{
   const static int Var;
};

// luabind module:
.def_readonly("Var", &Foo::Var);
// I've also tried
.def_readonly("Var", Foo::Var);
```

> ```
>  error: no matching function for call to ‘luabind::class_<Foo>::def_readonly(const char [6], const Foo&)’
>  note: template<class C, class D> luabind::class_& luabind::class_::def_readwrite(const char*, D C::*)
> ```

What have I missed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As clearly stated in the documentation](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#nested-scopes-and-static-functions), static functions (among other things) can't be added as members. They have to be scoped in a special `.scope` construct.

```
class_<foo>("foo")
    .def(constructor<>())
    .scope
    [
        class_<inner>("nested"),
        def("f", &f)
    ];
```

I don't know if the non-member function version of `def` has `readonly` versions for variables, but it may. If it doesn't, then you'll have to expose it as a function that returns the value.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I missed that this isn't only for static functions.